# Can I add text after the Dcount formula in unbound text field of Ms Access Form?

Tags: ms-access-2010, dcount

I want to add a text after Dcount formula in Ms Access Form. I use the unbound text field to use the DCount formula however I would like to add 'text' within the same field after Dcount formula finishes. Please advise how do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to just extend the formula with a string concatenation i.e. `=DCOUNT(....) & " your text"`, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you so much. It works!